# printing data at a array location directly after receiving the two digit address using cbreak(); <curses.h> and getch();

Tags: c, linux, arrays, input, terminal

I a a beginner at this, so if this is obvious, take it easy on me.
I am using C.

I am using cbreak(); from curses.h to take input realtime from the Linux terminal.
I am using getch(); to catch one input at a time up to two, and using those inputs to address a 2D array.

**What i would LIKE it to be doing is printing data at the array location directly after receiving the two digit address**. 
As it is, it is taking the first set of two digits, then printing the first array location as it receives the first number of the address of the second location.

Here is what i have:

```
   int northsouth[2]; //array to hold input
   int nschoice; //counter for for below

   int loopOn = 1; 
   int northSave;   //(confused me) places to save value of northSouth[] in attempt  
   int southSave;   //to print only after receiving two digits.

   while(loopOn != 0)
   {        
         for(nschoice = 0; nschoice < 2; ++nschoice)
         {
            northsouth[nschoice] = getch();
            if(nschoice == 1 && northsouth[0] != northSave && northsouth[1] != southSave)
            {


               strcat(input, l[northsouth[0] -= 48][northsouth[1] -= 48]);  
               printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
               printf("%s", input);
               northSave = northsouth[0];
               southSave = northsouth[1];
             }

         }

   }
```

Comment: This is a well-asked question, but I can't really tell what the problem is (though that might be attributable to the time and lack of coffee)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want to print after you read two digits. (not after every one).

If so, you should get the `if` and its whole block out of the `for` loop, so the `for` loop will read 2 digits, and the `if` will print.

Comment: As it is it actually does print after two digits, it's just that it prints what is located at the address located by the two digits I entered before the last one, as opposed to the very last two. If i enter "123", it is giving me what is located at 12 ((12)3), as opposed to giving me what is at 23 (1(23)). Leaving 1 ((1)23) for the address entered before.     When i take it out of the for loop it does not print at all, but i will re check this.